# Error while installing SilkJS

Tags: osx-mavericks, silkjs

I am trying to install SilkJS in mavericks, I am getting the following error.
Version of my XCode is 5.0.2 and I have downloaded latest version of silk from [github](https://github.com/mschwartz/SilkJS).

I have followed the instructions to install SilkJS from [website](http://www.silkjs.net/installing-silkjs/), I have got following error while performing "make" command in instruction 5.

```
In file included from ../src/accessors.cc:28:
In file included from ../src/v8.h:60:
In file included from ../src/objects-inl.h:38:
In file included from ../src/elements.h:33:
In file included from ../src/heap.h:41:
../src/store-buffer.h:229:9: error: private field 'heap_' is not used
      [-Werror,-Wunused-private-field]
  Heap* heap_;
        ^
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [/Users/sree/SilkJS/src/v8-read-only/out/x64.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/accessors.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ../src/assembler.cc:35:
In file included from ../src/assembler.h:38:
In file included from ../src/v8.h:60:
In file included from ../src/objects-inl.h:38:
In file included from ../src/elements.h:33:
In file included from ../src/heap.h:41:
../src/store-buffer.h:229:9: error: private field 'heap_' is not used
      [-Werror,-Wunused-private-field]
  Heap* heap_;
        ^
1 error generated.
In file included from ../src/ast.cc:28:
In file included from ../src/ast.h:31:
In file included from ../src/v8.h:60:
In file included from ../src/objects-inl.h:38:
In file included from ../src/elements.h:33:
In file included from ../src/heap.h:41:
../src/store-buffer.h:229:9: error: private field 'heap_' is not used
      [-Werror,-Wunused-private-field]
  Heap* heap_;
        ^
In file included from ../src/ast.cc:34:
../src/parser.h:99:8: error: private field 'owns_data_' is not used
      [-Werror,-Wunused-private-field]
  bool owns_data_;
       ^
make[3]: *** [/Users/sree/SilkJS/src/v8-read-only/out/x64.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/assembler.o] Error 1
2 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [/Users/sree/SilkJS/src/v8-read-only/out/x64.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/ast.o] Error 1
In file included from ../src/api.cc:28:
In file included from ../src/api.h:31:
In file included from ../src/v8.h:60:
In file included from ../src/objects-inl.h:38:
In file included from ../src/elements.h:33:
In file included from ../src/heap.h:41:
../src/store-buffer.h:229:9: error: private field 'heap_' is not used
      [-Werror,-Wunused-private-field]
  Heap* heap_;
        ^
In file included from ../src/api.cc:49:
../src/parser.h:99:8: error: private field 'owns_data_' is not used
      [-Werror,-Wunused-private-field]
  bool owns_data_;
       ^
2 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [/Users/sree/SilkJS/src/v8-read-only/out/x64.release/obj.target/v8_base/src/api.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [x64.release] Error 2
make[1]: *** [v8-read-only/out/x64.release/libv8_base.a] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```